# Can Redux store token sessions in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and React Native and would like know if I can implement and store token sessions in Redux for keeping the user logged in after they close and reopen the app. I have found out some people recommend AsyncStorage but my app state is handled with Redux.

This is my Redux store which uses AsyncStorage too.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import reducer from './reducers/index'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 0,
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

Would that be enough to keep a token session as I store other data in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redux store cannot restore data after closing and reopening the app.

import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

you can store by
AsyncStorage.setItem(userSessionKey, userData)

and restore by

```js
async function restoreSession() {
  try {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(userSessionKey)
    const userData = JSON.parse(data)
    if (userData !== null) {
      return userData
    } else {
      throw new Error('User Data is empty')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    //console.log(error)
    return null
  }
}
```

so, when the app starts, before navigating to main app,
restore the data, and add to redux store

Answer (score 1):

Redux can't persist/keep the data of the store/reducer when you kill the application.
But with the help of redux-persist library, redux can persist the data of the reducer/store. Also if you user reudx-persist you don't have to manually create AsyncStorage calls for retrieving initially when app starts redux-persist will handle that for you. You can use different storage engines not just AsyncStorage more info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#storage-engines)

In your case you can totally store user session token in redux with the help of redux-persist. Use Whitelist/blacklist in persist config to let redux-persist know which reducer to persist.
e.g.

```
// BLACKLIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['authReducer'] // navigation will not be persisted
};
 
// WHITELIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['authReducer'] // only navigation will be persisted
};
```